# initializing parent class attributes while making subclass Python

Tags: python, class, oop

Based on the classes below, I tried to make a dog that would allow instantiating all fields, and I tried:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, legs=4, animal_type='beast'):
        self.legs           = legs
        self.animal_type    = animal_type


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name=None, owner=None):
        self.name   = name
        self.owner  = owner

dog = Dog(legs=4, animal_type='dog', name='Fido', owner='Bob')

print dog.owner
print dog.name
```

which gave `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'legs'`

Based on [Initializing subclass variable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631152/initializing-subclass-variable-in-python) I tried

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, legs=4, animal_type='beast'):
        self.legs           = legs
        self.animal_type    = animal_type


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, legs=None, animal_type=None, name=None, owner=None):
        if legs:
            self.legs = legs
        if animal_type:
            self.animal_type = animal_type
        self.name   = name
        self.owner  = owner

dog = Dog(name='Fido', owner='Bob')

print dog.name
```

But here, I got a dog, but legs and animal_type didn't default, in fact, they didn't get set at all (pic below).

[image]

This example works to make a dog with 4 legs, but I don't have the ability to default and I have to give the legs and type or it won't create:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, legs=4, animal_type='beast'):
        self.legs           = legs
        self.animal_type    = animal_type


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, legs, animal_type, name=None, owner=None):
        if legs:
            self.legs = legs
        if animal_type:
            self.animal_type = animal_type
        self.name   = name
        self.owner  = owner

dog = Dog(4, 'dog', name='Fido', owner='Bob')

print dog.name
```

How can I subclass to be able to optionally overwrite parent attributes that default if they aren't given? So how can I take these classes Animal and Dog, and if I don't say the legs or type get a dog with legs=4, and animal_type=beast? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, legs=4, animal_type='beast'):
        self.legs        = legs
        self.animal_type = animal_type


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name=None, owner=None, **kwargs):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name  = name
        self.owner = owner

dog = Dog(legs=4, animal_type='dog', name='Fido', owner='Bob')
```

Capture the extra arguments in `**kwargs` and call the parent's constructor with them.